# Were the fabrials like soulcasters and regrowth casters made from hemalurgy by killing Radiants?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, stormlight-archive

Were the fabrials like soulcasters and regrowth casters made from hemalurgy by killing Radiants? I looked on the Coppermind and they say very little on the creation of the fabrials.

Comment: Could you please [edit] this to make it clear what the question here is?

Comment: -1  I think you should reread the books before trying to go deep into magic theory.

Answer (score 3):

In *Rhythm of War* it is revealed that:

> Soulcasters and other ancient fabrials were actually Spren that have manifested themselves in the material realm, and that the new fabrials that Navani is making are unnatural and offensive to the Spren as she is trapping them against their will instead of asking for their help.

Comment: While this is correct, pretty sure this was actually covered in Oathbringer.

Comment: You might be right, I just remember Navani talking to The Sibling and his reluctance to help her in any way because of her work with Fabrials. I am just beginning another read through of Oathbringer, and will update this answer if I find it in there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we have any real good reason to assume that fabrials were made by killing radiants, based on the books so far.

All the fabrials that we see being made involve enticing and then trapping a spren in a gem.  Metal is then typically used to activate and control the fabrial.

I don't see any reason to suspect that it's stolen from *radiants* with hemalurgy.

In particular, using hemalurgy on a Surgebinder is [quite difficult according to Brandon](https://wob.coppermind.net/adv_search/?query=hemalurgy%2Bsurgebinding).

(one example from the many in that search:)

> **Questioner**
>
> I was wondering if it is possible to steal Surgebinding with a Hemalurgic spike?
>
> **Brandon Sanderson**
>
> Yes, but if you're stealing it from a Radiant, you're going to be stealing the bond, which the spren has an influence over. So, it's maybe not going to work as well as you might hope.
>
> [source](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/402/#e13396)

It seems very unlikely that even the powerful ancient fabrials like soulcasters were made with this method, as stealing the powers from a Radiant is actually fairy hard to do with a hemalurgic spike.

One thing that we might not be able to rule out is that fabrial making involves hemalurgic spiking of spren in some way, to steal and use their powers.  That said, I don't think that really fits with what we've seen either.  Fabrials seem to utilize the power of a trapped spren, whereas hemalurgy typically involves *killing* to gain powers, instead of the trapping of a fabrial.  For that reason, I believe fabrials are more tied to the magic on Roshar than they are to any crossover with hemalurgy.

Comment: Not to say that fabrial makers like Navani never even heard about Scadrial, and Hemalurgy was a secret even there.

Comment: @Mithoron True, though to be fair Navani likely doesn't know much about the fabrials OP references anyways (like soulcasters); since those cannot be made by modern artifabrians AFAIK.  Even in the strange scenario where they are somehow connected, I wouldn't expect a conscious connection to hemalurgy.  At best I would think it would be more of a happy coincidence that they manage to take advantage of (assuming Intent could work like that, i.e. if they intend to use the sprens power without understanding hemalurgy it might still work).